# dplyr mutate converting "No" to 0 and "Yes" to 1

Tags: r, dplyr, recode

I have a column of type `chr` that I need as boolean (but leaving the NAs as NAs). The desired conversion is: No = 0, Yes = 1, NA = NA

```
tmp <- tibble(x = 1:7, y = c("No", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"))
```

I used the following to mutate; however I don't want a new variable but just change the original `y` variable:

```
tmp = tmp %>% mutate(
 z = case_when(
     y=="No" ~ 0,
     y=="Yes" ~ 1
 ))
```

Comment: Just changing `z` to `y` will get you the desired result as well

Comment: Oh dear!  I never even spotted that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just another solution which can be useful in case you will need to recode more values in the future

```
library(dplyr)
tmp$y <- recode(tmp$y, "No" = 0, "Yes" = 1)
```

or using `mutate` in a pipeline

```
tmp %>% 
  mutate(y = recode(y, "No" = 0, "Yes" = 1))
```

Output

```
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#       x     y
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1     1     0
# 2     2     1
# 3     3    NA
# 4     4     1
# 5     5     1
# 6     6     1
# 7     7     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
# base R style
tmp$y <- match(tmp$y, c("No","Yes")) - 1L

# tidyverse style
tmp <- tmp %>% 
  mutate(y = match(y, c("No","Yes")) - 1L)
```

which both give:

> ```
> > tmp
> # A tibble: 7 x 2
>       x     y
>   <int> <int>
> 1     1     0
> 2     2     1
> 3     3    NA
> 4     4     1
> 5     5     1
> 6     6     1
> 7     7     0
> ```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly do :

```
tmp$y <- +(tmp$y == 'Yes')
#similar to
#tmp$y <- as.integer(tmp$y == 'Yes')
tmp

# A tibble: 7 x 2
#      x     y
#  <int> <int>
#1     1     0
#2     2     1
#3     3    NA
#4     4     1
#5     5     1
#6     6     1
#7     7     0
```

Comment: Technically this changes `Yes` to `1`'s and everything else (except `NA`) to zero

Comment: Well, that is true.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work?

```
tmp %>% 
  mutate(y = 1*(y=="Yes"))

# A tibble: 7 x 2
      x     y
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     0
2     2     1
3     3    NA
4     4     1
5     5     1
6     6     1
7     7     0
```

Answer (score -1):

Yopu almost had it.

```
tmp <- tmp %>% mutate(y=ifelse(is.na(y), y, y == "Yes"))
```

Answer (score -1):

I came up with a quick and dirty fix using `ifelse()` function.

```
tmp <- tibble(x = 1:7, y = c("No", "Yes", NA, "Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No"))
tmp_new <- as_tibble(ifelse(is.na(tmp) == T,NA, ifelse(tmp == "No",0,1)))
```